# How to write a java for loop to load a map given a Set of id's and List of values

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

This is my crack at working with a HashMap. I'm attempting to use the keys (id's) and values (employeeNames), below. I need to write an enhanced for loop, but couldn't figure it out, so just trying a traditional for loop. I know this is really simple, but I'm new to Java.

My error:

> The method employeeNames(int) is undefined for the type App

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Map<Integer, String> employeeMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    
    employeeNames.add("Jim Jones");
    employeeNames.add("Earl Jones");
    employeeNames.add("Bob Jones");
    
    ids.add(1);
    ids.add(2);
    ids.add(3);
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeNames.size(); i++) {
        employeeMap.put(i, employeeNames(i));
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`employeeNames` is an `ArrayList`, so if you want get values from the list, use `employeeNames.get(i)` instead of `employeeNames(i)`.

And as I know, use `List<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<>()` instead of `List<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<String>()`, and that is the same to set.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me correct the format, I'm a newer in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If the ids is the indices of the employee in employeeNames:

```
ids.forEach(id -> employeeMap.put(id, employeeNames.get(id))
```

But than you need to change ids to:

```
ids.add(0)
ids.add(1)
ids.add(2)
```